# Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен Unit

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста. В unity работаю совсем не долго, как решать подобное?

[image: Unit]

Comment: Вы ничего не перепутали, че-то я не помню в C# встроенного типа Unit https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=213&clid=2051430&win=124&msid=1508756988.75514.22881.28419&text=c%23%20Unit

Comment: `Unit` - это ваш класс? Есть структура [Unit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit(v=vs.110).aspx) и перечисление [Unit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.CanvasScaler.Unit.html) которые маловероятно смогут помочь решить проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В описании ошибки чётко написано что надо сделать. Нажать <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> или <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> и из выпадающего списка выбрать нужное пространство имен.

Данная ошибка говорит о том, что класс `Unit` находится в каком-то из пространств имен, которое сейчас не подключено с помощью ключевого слова `using` в самом начале файла

Например в данном случае возможно может не хватать

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Или если это ваш класс, то вместо `UnityEngine.UI` надо подставить своё.

Но более подробный список можно увидеть нажав заветную комбинацию клавиш